# Microsoft Expression studio wont show up in start menu after installing expression blend 4.0

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have installed expression blend through BlendWPFSDK_en.msi. After installing it is not showing up in start menu. I have tried to right click on xaml file but still it is not showing up. I m using visual studio 2010. Am I missing something?
Please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: "*I have tried to right click on xaml file but still it is not showing up*". Try to right click on solution file (`.sln`)?

Comment: thanks for answer, i have installed on windows 7. I have tried it with .sln file but no luck

Comment: There is no specific step you need to do to make Blend works. Normal installation steps, and it should appear in context menu upon right clicking `.sln` file > open with. As most people will suggest, try to reinstall Blend.

Comment: sorry i downloaded only expression blend sdk. I uninstalled it then download Microsoft Expression Studio 4 Ultimate Trial. now it is showing up